# Formal definition for strings

Tags: string, ebnf

I was looking for a good formal structure for strings in a language, but I can't find one. The EBNF for C just has a class called string, and from python it has a const STRING as far as I've seen. 
So I was wondering if anyone had a good EBNF or regex that matches only valid strings within quotes. 
So it would match this: 
"Hello\nWorld!"
but not this:
"Hello\World!" since \W is not a control sequence.

Comment: Since different languages have different string literals you should probably specify the language if you want a regex string literal's for that language.

Comment: If I recall correctly, strings in False match the regex `"[^"]*"`.